# grep() doesn't match fully in for loops, only matching the exact characters

Tags: r, string, character

I have a DT `names_nightlight` has the standard region names as shown below. The other DT `disasters`, where one column `Location`, has standard and non-standard region names as well as city/municipality names. I want to replace the non-standard region names in `disasters$Location` with the standard region names from `names_nightlight$region`.

> names_nightlight:

```
|      country      |   region    | ISO |
|-------------------|-------------|-----|
| American Samoa    | Eastern     | ASM |
| American Samoa    | Manu'a      | ASM |
| American Samoa    | Unorganized | ASM |
| American Samoa    | Western     | ASM |
| Antigua & Barbuda | Barbuda     | ATG |
| Antigua & Barbuda | Redonda     | ATG |
| Antigua & Barbuda | Saint George| ATG |
| ...               | ...         | ... |
```

I need to use `grep()` to find matches, where `disasters$Location` has the region names, then make `disasters$Location := names_nightlight$region` (standard names) and mark it with `disasters$matched := 1`. Later, I can find the region for those city/municipality in disasters$Location manually with Google.

```
for (j in names_nightlight[!region == "just one region", ISO]){
    for (i in names_nightlight[ISO == j, region]){
        disasters[ISO == j][grep(i, Location), Location := i]
        disasters[ISO == j & Location == i, matched := 1]
    }
}
```

However, the grep function in my loops doesn't seem functioning fully, only the exact characters are matched. For example, "Manu'a island" isn't matched with "Manu'a", and "Saint George "  (ends with space) isn't matched with "Saint George" (ends without space).

In the results that don't have a match

```
disasters[is.na(matched) == TRUE]

| Start.date |  End.date  | ISO |   Location    |  Disaster.No. | matched |
|------------|------------|-----|---------------|---------------|---------|
| 2005-02-16 | 2005-02-16 | ASM | Manu'a island | 2005-0151     | NA      |
| 2017-09-06 | 2017-09-06 | ATG | Saint George  | 2017-0381     | NA      |
| 2017-09-06 | 2017-09-06 | ATG | Crosbies      | 2017-0381     | NA      |
| 2017-09-06 | 2017-09-06 | ATG | Fort Road     | 2017-0381     | NA      |
| 2017-09-06 | 2017-09-06 | ATG | Clare Hall    | 2017-0381     | NA      |
| 2017-09-06 | 2017-09-06 | ATG | Grays Farm    | 2017-0381     | NA      |
| ...        | ...        | ... | ...           | ...           | ...     |
```

> dput(names_nightlight[1:10])

```
structure(list(country = c("American Samoa", "American Samoa", 
"American Samoa", "American Samoa", "Antigua & Barbuda", "Antigua & Barbuda", 
"Antigua & Barbuda", "Antigua & Barbuda", "Antigua & Barbuda", 
"Antigua & Barbuda"), region = c("Eastern", "Manu'a", "Unorganized", 
"Western", "Barbuda", "Redonda", "Saint George", "Saint John", 
"Saint Mary", "Saint Paul"), ISO = c("ASM", "ASM", "ASM", "ASM", 
"ATG", "ATG", "ATG", "ATG", "ATG", "ATG")), row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7f835380dae0>)
```

> dput(disasters[1:10])

```
structure(list(Start.date = structure(c(12422, 12422, 12422, 
12422, 12830, 17415, 14167, 14167, 14167, 14167), class = "Date"), 
    End.date = structure(c(12422, 12422, 12422, 12422, 12830, 
    17415, 14168, 14168, 14168, 14168), class = "Date"), Country = c("American Samoa", 
    "American Samoa", "American Samoa", "American Samoa", "American Samoa", 
    "Anguilla", "Antigua and Barbuda", "Antigua and Barbuda", 
    "Antigua and Barbuda", "Antigua and Barbuda"), ISO = c("ASM", 
    "ASM", "ASM", "ASM", "ASM", "AIA", "ATG", "ATG", "ATG", "ATG"
    ), Location = c("Eastern", "Manu'a", "Unorganized", "Western", 
    "Manu'a island", "just one region", "Barbuda", "Redonda", 
    "Saint George", "Saint John"), Latitude = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_), Longitude = c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, 
    NA_real_), Magnitude.value = c(310, 310, 310, 310, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA), Magnitude.scale = c("Kph", "Kph", "Kph", 
    "Kph", "Kph", "Kph", "Kph", "Kph", "Kph", "Kph"), Disaster.type = c("Storm", 
    "Storm", "Storm", "Storm", "Storm", "Storm", "Storm", "Storm", 
    "Storm", "Storm"), Disaster.subtype = c("Tropical cyclone", 
    "Tropical cyclone", "Tropical cyclone", "Tropical cyclone", 
    "Tropical cyclone", "Tropical cyclone", "Tropical cyclone", 
    "Tropical cyclone", "Tropical cyclone", "Tropical cyclone"
    ), Associated.disaster = c("--", "--", "--", "--", "--", 
    "--", "Flood", "Flood", "Flood", "Flood"), Associated.disaster2 = c("--", 
    "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--", "--"), Total.deaths = c(0L, 
    0L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 4L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Total.affected = c(23060L, 
    23060L, 23060L, 23060L, 0L, 15000L, 25800L, 25800L, 25800L, 
    25800L), Total.damage...000.US.. = c(150000L, 150000L, 150000L, 
    150000L, 0L, 200000L, 0L, 0L, 0L, 0L), Insured.losses...000.US.. = c(0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 6700, 0, 0, 0, 0), Disaster.name = c("Heta", 
    "Heta", "Heta", "Heta", "Olaf", "Hurricane 'Irma'", "Hurricane \"Omar\"", 
    "Hurricane \"Omar\"", "Hurricane \"Omar\"", "Hurricane \"Omar\""
    ), Disaster.No. = c("2004-0004", "2004-0004", "2004-0004", 
    "2004-0004", "2005-0151", "2017-0381", "2008-0604", "2008-0604", 
    "2008-0604", "2008-0604"), empty_region = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
    1, 0, 0, 0, 0), matched = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA)), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x7f835380dae0>, row.names = c(NA, 
-10L), class = c("data.table", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Can you please make your question reproducible? `dput` comes very handy when it comes to communicating datasets.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik I just added some output from `dput(DT[1:10])` for example. Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you want to achieve but take note that:

```
disasters[ISO == j][grep(i, Location), Location := i]
```

does 'nothing' beacuse `disasters[ISO == j]` returns subseted data.table but you dont assing it to any variable and afterwards you do `[grep(i, Location), Location := i]` on object that is not assingned to any variable. This is not the same:

```
DT[some subseting, new_var := ...]
DT[some subseting][new_var := ...]
```

Read the `Note` section of `?":="`. So try to replace:

```
disasters[ISO == j][grep(i, Location), Location := i]
disasters[ISO == j & Location == i, matched := 1]
```

with:

```
disasters[ISO == j & str_detect(Location, i), ":="(Location = i, matched = 1)]
```

Comment: By `disasters[ISO == j]`, I am trying to avoid matches when there are similar region names across different countries.

Comment: I just tried your code. It gives me all the duplicate `Location` entries of only the first item matched by `i`. @det

Comment: @Ziroque Like I said I'm not sure what exactly you want. I have just pointed out part of the code that is probably not doing what you think it is and gave you suggestion how to fix it. That dosn't mean that rest of the code is good (or even 'fixed' part) for what you are trying to do.

Comment: @Ziroque You should probably write expected output. Also I'm not sure why do you need region. Can't you try something like:                                                              
 `for (i in unique(names_nightlight$region))
  disasters[str_detect(Location, i), ":="(Location = i, matched = 1)]`?

Comment: Thanks for your help and explanation. `str_detect()` worked.

Comment: Do you mind edit your answer to `str_detect()`, so that I can officially accept it and itmight help others later.

Comment: But what could possibly be the explanation here for `grep()` only matches the exact characters?

Comment: yeah sure, glad it worked. regarding `grep` I'm not rly sure, I almost always use `stringr` beacuse it has structural logic across package.